# Key word trasformations (Passive Voice)

Tags: passive-voice

I have a sentence:
It is believed that they cancelled their trip at the last moment.

I need to complete the second sentence, using the word given and use betwenn 2-5 words.

The word is BELIEVED

And here are the second sentence:
They ______ their trip at the last moment.

What should be here?

I think that there should be

They are believed to cancelled their trip at the last moment.

But my friend said there should be

They are believed to have cancelled their trip at the last moment.

What option is right?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence to be filled is:

> They ______ their trip at the last moment.

If you filled this sentence with "Are believed to cancelled", It would be grammatically wrong, Because we use  **TO** With Base form of verb. For examples: To play, To do, To work, To cancel.
etc.
I think this sentence should be filled as follows:

> They are believed to have cancelled their trip at the last moment.

Here, 'To have cancelled' is perfect infinitive form which works best in the your sentence.

Perfect form of infinitive is called Perfect infinitive. A Perfect infinitive is formed with **To have+past participle** And it refers to a time before that of the preceding verb. For an example:

> I'm glad to have studied at that school.

( Here the speaker is glad that he/she has studied at that school)

Here, **am** is the preceding verb. **I'm glad** refers to the present and 'To have studied' refers before of being glad.

We do use **Perfect infinitive** after some verbs. For more information,

check: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/perfect-infinitive-with-to-to-have-worked

---

***Reporting an earlier event in the passive voice***

If the reporting happens in the present and reported event in past we use the structure : **subject+passive reporting verb+To infinitive or perfect infinitive**

source: http://www.grammaring.com/reporting-an-earlier-event-in-the-passive-voice

For an example:

> He is believed never to have smiled at anyone.

Now, It should be clear to you that in your sentence reporting happens in the present and reported event is in past.

> They are believed= reporting in the present
>
> To have cancelled the trip at the last moment= Reported event is in the past